# UnsatisifiedLinkError - Any idea on how to fix this?

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitypeException: Could not load JIntellitype.dll from local file system or from inside JAR
    at com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype.<init>(JIntellitype.java:114)
    at com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype.getInstance(JIntellitype.java:174)
    at CaptureScreen.registerHotkeys(CaptureScreen.java:163)
    at CaptureScreen.<init>(CaptureScreen.java:100)
    at CaptureScreen.main(CaptureScreen.java:199)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\B\AppData\Local\Temp: Can't find    dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype.<init>(JIntellitype.java:99)
    ... 9 more
```

I get this error when I run from the command line, however, it does not cause any issues with my program running on my machine, however, on other peoples machines the program will not run at all.

I have never come across this error before and fairly confused.. mostly that it runs fine on my machine, but not on others even though it throws this error on both.

Comment: The JIntellitype library uses JNI to invoke native code in JIntellitype.dll, but it can't find the DLL. It looks like the DLL is stored as a jarfile resource the program tries to unpack it to the temp directory at runtime to load it from there, but something is wrong and the file isn't actually there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classpath error. Its likely that you have it set up right for compile time but not runtime. Make sure that either your jar is in the right location and/or that you've set your classpath to include the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Jintellitype website, download the source, add it to your download folder and then move the .dll files into the folder with the Jitellitype classes after building the project