# UnsatisfiedLinkError swig_module_init

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate Doubango API for SIP calling in Android. I am done with the initial setup as described [here](http://stage.dcaa.gov.ae/RegisterDocuments/android-ngn-stack-00.pdf), but when I launch this app on a real device/simulator, I always end up with the below crash.

I have gone through these questions already:

- [UnsatisfiedLinkError : setMessageHandler(Native Method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940541/unsatisfiedlinkerror-setmessagehandlernative-method)
- [UnsatisifiedLinkError - Any idea on how to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368114/unsatisifiedlinkerror-any-idea-on-how-to-fix-this)

LOGCAT

```
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at org.doubango.tinyWRAP.SipCallback.<init>(SipCallback.java:54)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at com.example.siptest.NSipManager$1.<init>(NSipManager.java:38)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at com.example.siptest.NSipManager.<init>(NSipManager.java:38)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at com.example.siptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: swig_module_init
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at org.doubango.tinyWRAP.tinyWRAPJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at org.doubango.tinyWRAP.tinyWRAPJNI.<clinit>(tinyWRAPJNI.java:777)
04-15 18:41:48.162: E/AndroidRuntime(5761):     ... 18 more
```

**EDIT**
Doubango provides a library project named android-ngn-stack(default) having all the .so file and a jar named simple-xml-2.3.4.jar.
i have added library android-ngn-stack in my project as well build path contains simple-xml-2.3.4.jar.

I think android-ngn-stack will handle the calls to native code, right?

code for loading .so in libraray is as follows:

```
    static{
    NgnEngine.initialize2();
}

// This function will be renamed as "initialize()" when "initialize()" get removed
private static void initialize2(){
    // do not add try/catch to let the app die if libraries are missing or incompatible
    if(!sInitialized){
        // See 'http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/issues/detail?id=197' for more information
        // Load Android utils library (required to detect CPU features)
        boolean haveLibUtils = new File(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libutils_armv5te.so")).exists();
        if (haveLibUtils) { // only "armeabi-v7a" comes with "libutils.so"
            System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libutils_armv5te.so"));
            Log.d(TAG,"CPU_Feature="+AndroidUtils.getCpuFeatures());
            if(NgnApplication.isCpuNeon()){
                Log.d(TAG,"isCpuNeon()=YES");
                System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP_neon.so"));
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG,"isCpuNeon()=NO");
                System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP.so"));
            }
        }
        else {
            // "armeabi", "mips", "x86"...
            System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP.so"));
        }

        // If OpenSL ES is supported and know to work on current device then used it
        if(NgnApplication.isSLEs2KnownToWork()){
            final String pluginPath = String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libplugin_audio_opensles.so");

            // returned value is the number of registered add-ons (2 = 1 consumer + 1 producer)
            if(MediaSessionMgr.registerAudioPluginFromFile(pluginPath) < 2){
                // die if cannot load add-ons
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to register audio plugin with path=" + pluginPath);
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Using OpenSL ES audio driver");
        }
        // otherwise, use AudioTrack/Record
        else{
            ProxyAudioProducer.registerPlugin();
            ProxyAudioConsumer.registerPlugin();
        }

        ProxyVideoProducer.registerPlugin();
        ProxyVideoConsumer.registerPlugin();

        SipStack.initialize();

        NgnProxyPluginMgr.Initialize();

        sInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

method of tinyWRAPJNI from the library that shows missing is as follows

```
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
     * Version 2.0.9
     *
     * Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
     * the SWIG interface file instead.
     * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

  //..................lots of code here
  private final static native void swig_module_init();
  static {
      swig_module_init();
  }
```

**EDIT 2**
Loading .so source code followed by LOGCAT detail:

```
private static void initialize2(){
    // do not add try/catch to let the app die if libraries are missing or incompatible
    if(!sInitialized){
        // See 'http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/issues/detail?id=197' for more information
        // Load Android utils library (required to detect CPU features)
        boolean haveLibUtils = new File(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libutils_armv5te.so")).exists();
        if (haveLibUtils) { // only "armeabi-v7a" comes with "libutils.so"
            System.loadLibrary("utils_armv5te");
            System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libutils_armv5te.so"));
            Log.d(TAG,"CPU_Feature="+AndroidUtils.getCpuFeatures());
            if(NgnApplication.isCpuNeon()){
                Log.d(TAG,"isCpuNeon()=YES");
                System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP_neon.so"));
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG,"isCpuNeon()=NO");
                System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP.so"));
            }
        }
        else {
            // "armeabi", "mips", "x86"...
            System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP.so"));
        }

        // If OpenSL ES is supported and know to work on current device then used it
        if(NgnApplication.isSLEs2KnownToWork()){
            final String pluginPath = String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libplugin_audio_opensles.so");

            // returned value is the number of registered add-ons (2 = 1 consumer + 1 producer)
            if(MediaSessionMgr.registerAudioPluginFromFile(pluginPath) < 2){
                // die if cannot load add-ons
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to register audio plugin with path=" + pluginPath);
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Using OpenSL ES audio driver");
        }
        // otherwise, use AudioTrack/Record
        else{
            ProxyAudioProducer.registerPlugin();
            ProxyAudioConsumer.registerPlugin();
        }

        ProxyVideoProducer.registerPlugin();
        ProxyVideoConsumer.registerPlugin();

        SipStack.initialize();

        NgnProxyPluginMgr.Initialize();

        sInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
04-17 05:36:34.929: D/gralloc_goldfish(21422): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-17 05:37:29.919: D/dalvikvm(21422): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.siptest-2/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce65e8
04-17 05:37:29.919: D/dalvikvm(21422): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.siptest-2/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce65e8
04-17 05:37:29.919: D/dalvikvm(21422): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.siptest-2/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce65e8, skipping init
04-17 05:37:58.719: D/dalvikvm(21422): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.siptest/lib/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce65e8
04-17 05:37:58.719: D/dalvikvm(21422): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.siptest/lib/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce65e8
04-17 05:37:58.719: D/dalvikvm(21422): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.siptest/lib/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce65e8, skipping init
04-17 05:43:12.819: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(21422): CPU_Feature=15
04-17 05:43:21.229: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(21422): isCpuNeon()=YES
04-17 05:43:26.459: D/dalvikvm(21422): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.siptest/lib/libtinyWRAP_neon.so 0x40ce65e8
04-17 05:43:26.479: D/dalvikvm(21422): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.siptest/lib/libtinyWRAP_neon.so 0x40ce65e8
04-17 05:43:26.479: D/dalvikvm(21422): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.siptest/lib/libtinyWRAP_neon.so 0x40ce65e8, skipping init
04-17 05:43:41.939: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnApplication(21422): sGlEsVersion=0
04-17 05:43:42.050: D/dalvikvm(21422): GC_CONCURRENT freed 86K, 7% free 2719K/2924K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 74ms
04-17 05:43:42.129: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(21422): Configure AEC[true/200] AEC_TAIL_ADAPT[true] NoiseSuppression[true], Voice activity detection[false]
04-17 05:43:42.149: I/System.out(21422): org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine@40d31c10
```

**EDIT 3**

```
private static final String LIBS_FOLDER = NgnApplication.getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir;
    // This function will be renamed as "initialize()" when "initialize()" get removed
    private static void initialize2(){
        // do not add try/catch to let the app die if libraries are missing or incompatible
        if(!sInitialized){
            // See 'http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/issues/detail?id=197' for more information
            // Load Android utils library (required to detect CPU features)
            Log.d(TAG, "*************************");
            Log.d(TAG,NgnApplication.getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir);
            Log.d(TAG, "*************************");
            boolean haveLibUtils = new File(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libutils_armv5te.so")).exists();
            if (haveLibUtils) { // only "armeabi-v7a" comes with "libutils.so"
//              System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libutils_armv5te.so"));
//              Log.d(TAG,"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                System.loadLibrary("utils_armv5te");
                Log.d(TAG,"CPU_Feature="+AndroidUtils.getCpuFeatures());
                if(NgnApplication.isCpuNeon()){
                    Log.d(TAG,"isCpuNeon()=YES");
                    System.loadLibrary("tinyWRAP_neon");
//                  System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP_neon.so"));
                }
                else{
                    Log.d(TAG,"isCpuNeon()=NO");
                    System.loadLibrary("tinyWRAP");
//                  System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP.so"));
                }
            }
            else {
                // "armeabi", "mips", "x86"...
//              System.load(String.format("%s/%s", NgnEngine.LIBS_FOLDER, "libtinyWRAP.so"));
                System.loadLibrary("tinyWRAP");
                Log.d(TAG,"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
            }




04-17 11:23:31.224: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnApplication(1617): Build.MODEL=sdk
04-17 11:23:31.224: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnApplication(1617): Build.VERSION.SDK=17
04-17 11:23:31.234: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(1617): *************************
04-17 11:23:31.254: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(1617): /data/app-lib/org.doubango.test.call-1
04-17 11:23:31.254: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(1617): *************************
04-17 11:23:31.264: D/dalvikvm(1617): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.doubango.test.call-1/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce4298
04-17 11:23:31.294: D/dalvikvm(1617): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.doubango.test.call-1/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce4298
04-17 11:23:31.294: D/dalvikvm(1617): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.doubango.test.call-1/libutils_armv5te.so 0x40ce4298, skipping init
04-17 11:23:31.334: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(1617): CPU_Feature=15
04-17 11:23:31.334: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(1617): isCpuNeon()=YES
04-17 11:23:31.374: D/dalvikvm(1617): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.doubango.test.call-1/libtinyWRAP_neon.so 0x40ce4298
04-17 11:23:31.404: D/dalvikvm(1617): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.doubango.test.call-1/libtinyWRAP_neon.so 0x40ce4298
04-17 11:23:31.404: D/dalvikvm(1617): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.doubango.test.call-1/libtinyWRAP_neon.so 0x40ce4298, skipping init
04-17 11:23:31.764: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnApplication(1617): sGlEsVersion=0


04-17 16:57:38.300: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnApplication(844): Build.MODEL=sdk
04-17 16:57:38.310: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnApplication(844): Build.VERSION.SDK=10
04-17 16:57:38.320: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(844): *************************
04-17 16:57:38.320: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(844): /data/data/org.doubango.test.call/lib
04-17 16:57:38.320: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(844): *************************
04-17 16:57:38.380: D/dalvikvm(844): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.doubango.test.call/lib/libtinyWRAP.so 0x40515ea0
04-17 16:57:38.400: D/dalvikvm(844): Added shared lib /data/data/org.doubango.test.call/lib/libtinyWRAP.so 0x40515ea0
04-17 16:57:38.400: D/dalvikvm(844): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.doubango.test.call/lib/libtinyWRAP.so 0x40515ea0, skipping init
04-17 16:57:38.400: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnEngine(844): $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
04-17 16:57:38.470: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnApplication(844): sGlEsVersion=0
```

Comment: Tell us what you have done to verify that the .so is in the APK and getting unpacked on the device.  Show us the Native code which defines this function, and the Java code where it is declared as a native method.  Show the code which loads the JNI library, and the logcat messages generated as a result.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i have edited the question with the info you require. will you provide any hint how to deal with it? thanks

Comment: Add the logcat messages generated by the library loading attempt.  The code used there is risky as it attempts to specify the library location rather than letting android do that, and the location has recently changed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for pointing me in this direction, i have edited the question to have the details of .so file loading. I observed from debugging that .so file is available under lib(havLibUtils) still  its not able to Load either by specifying library location(System.Load()) or by System.loadLibrary(). How to fix this issue?

Comment: Which exact library is failing to load?

Comment: all of them are failing to load and scenario varies on the basis of testing platform. In Edit 3 of question you can see that i have used NgnApplication.getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir to get the path. I have tested this code in two environment SDK 10 and SDK17 (logcat available in question). In SDK17 File.exists() method finds the .so inside lib still not able to load libutils_armv5te.so, libtinyWRAP_neon.so while in SDK 10 File.exists() method failed to find the .so file in lib and also fails in loading libtinyWRAP.so.

Comment: The messages you posted indicate successful loading of many libraries.

Comment: then what is the meaning of No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.doubango.test.call-1/libtinyWRAP_neon.so that appears with each call to load()? If its a warning then its ok. Do you have any idea why File.exists() method failed to find .so inside lib on SDK 10? thanks for your time.

Comment: It means you have no JNI_OnLoad, but that is optional and most libraries don't have one.  So in a way it is a "success" message.  Presumably File.exists() would fail because the file is not precisely there - with a debug apk you can use run-as in the adb shell to look around.  I think the install location depends on the device Android version, not the SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your `.so` files and go  `Build Path -> Add to build Path`.

I had the same issue and resolved using the way I wrote above..

Hope it will help you too...

Comment: i dont think so, please review the content under EDIT2 in question. It ensures that .so file is available in apk still system is not able to load these files.

Comment: Still i tried to do the same as suggested but its resulting in error in library project.

Comment: Yes I understand .. Please try once .. and also try to check Android Dependencies from order and Export by right click on project ..